# Some files are deleted from the files table after CRON execution

Tags: forms, files, cron

I am using `hook_form_alter()` to add a file upload field to the taxonomy term form. 
The form itself and the submit are working well. From the submit callback i save the uploaded file using `file_save_upload()`. This also works well, the is saved in `sites/default/files` and in the `files` database. I have noticed that when Drupal CRON is executed the files i saved are deleted, but the other files (from CCK for example) remains in the table. Files are also deleted from the `sites/default/files` directory.

Here is my code :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function community_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'taxonomy_form_term':
      // get the current image if any
      $image = variable_get('community_term_image_'.$form['tid']['#value'], '');
      // load file
      if($image) $image = field_file_load($image);
      $form['identification']['image_preview'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#value' => $image ? theme_imagecache('community-section-title', $image['filepath']) : '',
      );
      $form['identification']['image'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Category image'),
        '#type' => 'file',
      );
      $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
      $form['#submit'][] = 'community_term_form_image_submit';
    break;
  }
}

function community_term_form_image_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $dir = variable_get('file_directory_path', 'files');
  $save = file_save_upload('image', array(), $dir);
  if($save->fid) {
    // If the term currently contains a picture, we remove it prior to saving
    // the new one
    $current_image = variable_get('community_term_image_'.$form_state['values']['tid'], '');
    if($current_image) {
      $current_image = field_file_load($current_image);
      db_query('DELETE FROM {files} WHERE fid = %d', $current_image['fid']);
      file_delete($current_image['filepath']);
    }
    variable_set('community_term_image_'.$form_state['values']['tid'], $save->fid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`file_save_upload()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6):

> The source file is validated as a proper upload and handled as such.
>   The file will be added to the files table as a temporary file.
>   Temporary files are periodically cleaned. To make the file permanent
>   file call file_set_status() to change its status.

You need to use [file_set_status()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_set_status/6) to change the status of the file.

```
  $save = file_save_upload('image', array(), $dir);
  if($save->fid) {
    file_set_status($save,FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT);
    ...
```